# Remove multiple elements after animation in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a number of X boxes created dynamically, as I can add and remove any number of them. I added a small animation (".show('250')") when boxes are created, and now I want to do the same when boxes are removed.

```
for (let i = 0; i < boxes_to_remove;i++) {
  $('[id^=box_]:last-child').remove();
}
```

This is working fine, but I want to add the same animation (well, a fadeOut...) to the previous code, but isn't working. So far I've tried:

```
  $('[id^=box_]:last-child')
    .fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    })
```

and

```
  $('[id^=box_]:last-child')
    .animate({height: 0}, 250,"linear",function() {
            $(this).remove();
    })
```

^This removes only the last one. Does the animation I want to but if I pass "delete 4 boxes" only deletes the last one.

```
  $('[id^=box_]:last-child')
    .fadeOut("250")
    .remove();
```

^This does the opposite. If I want to delete 4 boxes, it deletes 4 boxes but with no animation.

TL;DR: I want to apply an animation and then delete an element X times in a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because while the loop runs, no element was removed yet so `:last_child` always points to the same element. You have to run it pseudo recursively, so that the next `:last_child` is determined after the previous one was removed:

```js
function remove(n) {
  $('[id^=box_]:last-child')
    .fadeOut("250", function() {
      $(this).remove();
      if (n > 1) remove(n - 1);
    });
}
remove(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box_1">1</div>
  <div id="box_2">2</div>
  <div id="box_3">3</div>
  <div id="box_4">4</div>
  <div id="box_5">5</div>
  <div id="box_6">6</div>
</div>
```